# Subtracting elements at specified indices in array

Tags: arrays, scala, scala-collections

I am beginner to functional programming and Scala. I have an Array of arrays which contain `Double` numerals. I want to subtract elements (basically two arrays, see example) and I am unable to find online how to do this.

For example, consider

```
val instance = Array(Array(2.1, 3.4, 5.6), 
                  Array(4.4, 7.8, 6.7))
```

I want to subtract `4.4 from 2.1`, `7.8 from 3.4` and `6.7 from 5.6`

Is this possible in Scala?

Apologies if the question seems very basic but any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.zip`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq):

```
scala> instance(1).zip(instance(0)).map{ case (a,b) => a - b}
res3: Array[Double] = Array(2.3000000000000003, 4.4, 1.1000000000000005)
```

`instance(1).zip(instance(0))` makes an array of tuples `Array((2.1,4.4), (3.4,7.8), (5.6,6.7))`from corresponding pairs in your array

`.map{ case (a,b) => a - b}` or `.map(x => x._1 - x._2)` is doing subtraction for every tuple.

I would also recommend to use tuple instead of your top-level array:

```
val instance = (Array(2.1, 3.4, 5.6), Array(4.4, 7.8, 6.7))
```

So now, with additional definitions, it looks much better

```
scala> val (a,b) = instance
a: Array[Double] = Array(2.1, 3.4, 5.6)
b: Array[Double] = Array(4.4, 7.8, 6.7)

scala> val sub = (_: Double) - (_: Double) //defined it as function, not method
sub: (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>

scala> a zip b map sub.tupled
res20: Array[Double] = Array(2.3000000000000003, 4.4, 1.1000000000000005)
```

*`sub.tupled` allows `sub`-function to receive tuple of 2 parameters instead of just two parameters here.

Comment: "substr"? Known to most people as substring, I claim!

Comment: how about same old x86 assembler command, or is it associating with "submarine"? :)